# why the number of phonemes for speaking and alphabet for writing (वर्णों की कुल संख्या) in 'Sanskrit' language is fixed and specific?

Tags: sanskrit, devanagari

In the given below sentences the word,

*'sound' means any sound wave. I am not asking/talking about the meaning of that sound. That sound can be meaningless too.*

**I am curious about, why can't it be possible, that there can exist some sound which, can not be written and pronounced using alphabets and phonemes of 'Sanskrit' respectively?

If no, then How was it convinced or proved or known that these fixed and specific number of phonemes and alphabets will be sufficient to write and pronounce any sound.

Thank you

Comment: I didn't vote, but I guess the question is getting downvoted because you have written some (wrong) assumptions as if they were facts.

Answer (score 4):

There were no "developers" or "creators" of Sanskrit, or any other language except [conlangs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructed_language). The scripts used for Sanskrit also evolved organically, from the original [Brahmi script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmi_script), and although Devanagari is normally used for Sanskrit today, other scripts have been used in the past.

I don't think anybody sober has ever claimed that Devanagari contains signs (not alphabets: Devanagari *is* an alphabet, or more specifically an [abugida](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abugida), though I know in Indian English, "alphabets" colloquially refers to letters or signs) for all possible sounds, just [the ones that Sanskrit actually uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskrit_grammar#Phonology).

Can the Latin alphabet express all sounds of English? Not in its original form, and it does so now only in a very haphazard way. Deliberate design is not often found in languages, or their scripts, although it can be found to a larger extent in writing systems than in spoken languages.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Devanagari script has no means to write the [click sounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_consonant) of the languages of Southern Africa (it surely hadn't that means in antiquity, and I am not aware of modern extensions of Devanagari to cover them). This example answers the first question asked. BTW, Devanagari was extended for some of the English vowel phonemes like the aw in "law" in modern times.

The second question can be answered like this: The phoneme inventory of Sanskrit is proven by the fact that the orthography works well for that language. There are also phonological analyses of Sanskrit by ancient grammarians like Panini confirming the set of phonemes specific to that language.